# UILabel: Prevent method sizeToFit to modify width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

I'm trying to make my `UILabel` auto adjust its height to different input strings. While calling `sizeToFIt` does readjust the `UILabel` size, it also readjusts its width!!! I need a uniform width, thus I have the `COMMENT_WIDTH` constant. The weird part is that I have the exact same code in a previous project and the width of the `UILabel` remains constant after the method is called. Any ideas?

```
#define COMMENT_WIDTH 209

UILabel *comment        = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, COMMENT_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
comment.font            = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:12.0f];
comment.numberOfLines   = 200;
comment.text            = quote.content;
comment.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

[comment sizeToFit];
```

I did an NSLog before and after sizeToFit method and here are some of my outputs for different string inputs. Notice that the width AND height changes.

```
[2013-12-11 17:58:52.911 Inspyr[37855:70b] Before width: 209.000000, height : 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 

[2013-12-11 17:58:52.911 Inspyr[37855:70b] After width: 111.000000, height : 21.000000 

2013-12-11 17:58:52.911 Inspyr[37855:70b] Before width: 209.000000, height : 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 

2013-12-11 17:58:52.911 Inspyr[37855:70b] After width: 36.000000, height : 21.000000
```

Comment: Did the label in your previous project have a width constraint, or constraints to the left and right sides of its superview?

Comment: Don't think so, I'm instantiating the UILabel on its own. Can you elaborate on what a width constraint is?

Comment: A width constraint is an NSLayoutConstraint (part of the auto layout system) that defines the width of an object.

Comment: Got it. How would I add a width constraint in code (or set a mimiim width)? From what I've been researching, sizeToFit can set the width to be lower than the one I initially set.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to add a constraint. I tried your code, and it worked fine for me. You're already giving it a fixed width with your frame.

Comment: Here's an example of a string I used, its a quote: "Profits are to business as breathing is to life. Breathing is essential to life, but it is not the purpose for living. Similarly, profits are essential for the existence of the corporation, but they\\'re not the reason for its existence". The height of this UILabel should be 86, but it output 203.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43004/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-blee908)

Answer (score 0):

sizeToFit will resize your UILabel frame to the smallest frame possible considering your text, regardless of the frame you manually set before.  Just use sizeToFit, then get the frame, change its width, and set it to the UILabel:

```
[comment sizeToFit];
CGRect newCommentFrame = comment.frame;
newCommentFrame.size.width = COMMENT_WIDTH;
comment.frame = newCommentFrame;
```

Comment: Here's an example of a string I used, its a quote: "Profits are to business as breathing is to life. Breathing is essential to life, but it is not the purpose for living. Similarly, profits are essential for the existence of the corporation, but they\\'re not the reason for its existence". The height of this UILabel should be 86, but it output 203.

Comment: Instead of using sizeToFit, try using `CGSize aSize = [comment sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(COMMENT_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)];` and then `comment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, aSize.width, aSize.height);`  Does this produce any different result?

Comment: I found out the answer. Somehow, it was sizing my label with font size 17, (even though I specifically set it to 12). That's why the height was disproportionally large.